# Python is facing an overhead every 98 executions?

Tags: python, pandas, overhead

I have a big database, I just want to assign a constant to a new column. At the first executions (from 1 to 97); everything is fine, the code runs fast. Then the memory rockets at the iteration 98, then it's fine until the iteration 196 (98 iterations after) where the RAM rockets again, then the loop continues the memory rockets at every `i` where `i` is a multiplication of 98...

I guess that the mysterious number 98 may vary according to your PC.
And you may have to change the database size in order to reproduce the problem.

Here is my code

**Edit**: I think that's not garbage collection, because the `gc.isenabled()` returns `False` at the end of the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 2000000
data = pd.DataFrame({'a' : range(n)})
for i in range(1, 100):
    data['col_' + str(i)] = np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], n)

gc.disable()
for i in range(1, 600):
    data['test_{}'.format(i)] = i
    print(str(i)) # slow at every i multiplication of 98

gc.isenabled()
> False
```

And here is my memory usage, the peaks are at the iteration `i*98` (where `i` is an integer)

I'm on Windows 10, Python 3.6.1 | Anaconda 4.4.0 | pandas 0.24.2

I have 16 GB RAM & 8 core CPU

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's garbage collection.

Comment: @Barmar I can get that automatic garbage collection cleans the memory AFTER the iteration 98 (after the peaks) but I don’t get why AT i=98 the memory bumps up

Comment: It may be rebuilding a hash table as it crosses various size boundaries. So it temporarily has two copies, then the old one becomes garbage.

Comment: @Barmar I’m newbie to python, can you elaborate? And what would be a possible solution?

Comment: When you create a list or dictionary, Python allocates a certain amount of memory for it. As you keep adding to it, it eventually uses up that memory and has to make it bigger. It does this by allocating a larger block of memory, copying the old contents to the new memory, then freeing the old block.

Comment: While it's doing that copy it temporarily needs memory for the old and new copies, but it goes away when the copy is done. That's why you see a short burst of memory use, then it goes back down. This shouldn't normally be a problem, since it's just a temporary increase.

Comment: Research ways to specify the size of the dataframe when creating it, so it will allocate all the memory at once instead of growing it dynamically.

Comment: Why at `i=98` it's doing the copy of the data, but not at `i=97` or `i=99`?  That's mysterious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195346/discussion-between-metariat-and-barmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I want to confirm the same behavior on Ubuntu with 16 GB of RAM and GC being disabled. Therefore, it is definitely not an issue with GC or Windows memory management.

Secondly, on my system it slows down after every 99 iterations: after 99, after 198, after 297, etc. Anyway, I have a rather limited Swap file, so when the RAM+Swap is filled, then it crashes with a following stacktrace:

```
294
295
296
297
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'test_298'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1053, in set
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'test_298'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py-memory-test.py", line 12, in <module>
    data['test_{}'.format(i)] = i
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3370, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3446, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3172, in _set_item
    self._data.set(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1056, in set
    self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1184, in insert
    self._consolidate_inplace()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 929, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1899, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 3149, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError
```

Thus, it seems that `pandas` does some kind of merging/consolidation/repacking on insert sometimes. Let's take a look on the [core/internals/managers.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/224362951942e1f4e05fb8948596620aedac26d9/pandas/core/internals/managers.py#L1179)'s `insert` function, it has following lines:

```
def insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates=False):
    ...
    self._known_consolidated = False

    if len(self.blocks) > 100:
        self._consolidate_inplace()
```

I guess this is exactly what we were looking for!

Each time we are doing `insert` new block is created. When the number of blocks exceeds some limit, extra work (consolidation) is performed. Difference between 100 blocks limit in the code and our obtained empirically numbers around 98-99 may be explained by the presence of some extra dataframe meta-data which requires some room for, too.

**UPD**: in order to proof this hypothesis I have tried to change 100 -> 1000000 and it worked just fine, no performance gaps, no `MemoryError`. However, there is no public API to modify this parameter in the run-time, it is simply hardcoded.

**UPD2**: submitted an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26985) to `pandas`, since `MemoryError` doesn't look like an appropriate behavior for such a simple program.

Comment: So to eliminate this behavior, I should increase the number 100 to 10000?

Comment: This is a `pandas` core code, so the answer is yes, you can change this number locally in your `pandas` distribution, but there is no public API to change it during run-time. I even tried to check it, everything went smoothly and without MemoryError, updated the answer

Comment: I didn't find the `internals` folder inside my installed pandas packaged, so i'm not able to modify it ...

Comment: Probably you are looking inside wrong directory. Try to figure out `pandas` location using this SO question and answers there. Also Windows distribution structure may be different, so try to search for `managers.py` file in Explorer.

Comment: I was searching in AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas

Comment: it is not available in my version: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v0.20.1

Comment: No, it is there, just a different file https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.1/pandas/core/internals.py#L3845